# Show last post of employee in his profile page

Tags: posts, author

I have built a wordpress theme in which I have listed employees of the organization via custom post type. And I am displaying each employee via custom post type.

The employees listed are authors in my website too and they regularly write posts. When I am viewing each employees Profile page, I want to show the lst post written by that employee.

I hope I am clear in my explanation.

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get the most recent post by a given Author, just un-comment one of the two lines as appropriate. See the Codex for [more info on WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

The Codex entry is pretty long, so scroll down to the [Parameters section](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters) for more info on the various options you can filter your query with.

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(

    // get most recent post by Author's nickname (not username!)
//    'author_name'    => 'Joe'

    // get most recent post by Author's ID
//    'author'         => 7,

    'posts_per_page' => 1,
));
```

Comment: Getting author's post is easy....but what I want is completely different. Let me clarify my question again:

I am showing employee's profile in my site via custom post type. So when I am viewing an employees profile page (which is not via author.php), I want to show the latest post written by him....assuming that employee is an author on the site.

Comment: @AjayM, please, add details to the Question itself. As you can see, it was already misinterpreted... Myself, I inderstood you were talking about `/wp-admin/profile.php`. Show your code, template name, etc.